# client side Validation error message showing outside partial view using mvc 4 razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

my view has 3 tab say 'tab1','tab2' and 'tab3'.
when i tried to load the content of 'tab1' in ClientDetailTemplate of kendo grid of 'tab2' for some purpose.loded content has some input control and buttons. when i clicked on submit button form not valid but showing validation message on right away(out side).validation message displays properly on 'tab1'.

The code in 'tab1' which i wants to load in ClientDetailTemplate of kendo grid of 'tab2'.Validation message displays properly on 'tab1'

```
@{ Layout = null;
ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();}

@model PatientPortal.Model.Data.CommunicationMessasge
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Validators/_SendMessage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")"></script>

 @using (Html.BeginForm("SendMessageView", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "_sendMessageViewForm" }))
 {
     <table class="formStyle" style="margin-top: 10px;width:100%;" >


            <tr>
       <td colspan="2">
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="width:10%; " >
         <span class="bText">*</span>To:
        </td>
        <td style="width:90%;" >
            @(Html.Kendo().AutoCompleteFor(m=>m.MessageTo)
      .Name("MessageTo")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:60%;" })
      .DataTextField("FirstNameWithEmail")
      .Filter("contains")
      .Separator(",")
      .DataSource(source =>
      {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Action("GetPortalUsers", "Home").Data("onAdditionalData");
          }).ServerFiltering(true);
      })
      .Filter("startswith")
      .MinLength(1)
      .Height(150)
      .Template("<dl>" +
                            "<dd style='height:5px;vertical-align:central;' >${ data.FirstName } ${ data.LastName }</dd>" +
                        "</dl>")
        )
        </td>
     </tr>
                    <tr>
        <td style="width:10%;" >
         CC:
        </td>
        <td style="width:90%;"  >
            @(Html.Kendo().AutoCompleteFor(m=>m.CopyTo)
      .Name("CopyTo")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:60%;" })
      .DataTextField("FirstNameWithEmail")
      .Filter("contains")
      .Separator(",")
      .DataSource(source =>
      {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Action("GetPortalUsers", "Home").Data("onCopyTo");
          }).ServerFiltering(true);
      })
      .Filter("startswith")
      .MinLength(1)
      .Height(150)
      .Template("<dl>" +
                            "<dd style='height:5px;vertical-align:central;' >${ data.FirstName } ${ data.LastName }</dd>" +
                        "</dl>")
        )
        </td>
     </tr>

    <tr>
       <td style="width:10%;">
        Subject:
        </td>
        <td style="width:90%;">
              @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Subject, new { style = "width:60%;",pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9@.]*" })
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:10%;">
        <span class="bText">*</span>Message:
        </td>
        <td style="width:90%;">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Comments, new { style = "width:60%;", rows="20"})
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="width:10%;" >

        </td>
        <td style="width:90%;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="cbSaveAsDraft" id="cbSaveAsDraft"  checked="checked" style="width:20px;">Save Message in Sent Folder
        </td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.MessageId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.MessageFrom)

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnSend" value="Send" style="width: 100px;" class="k-button" onclick="PostMessageDetails(1)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="btnReply"  value="Reply" style="width: 100px; display:none;" class="k-button" onclick="    PostMessageDetails(2)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="btnForword" value="Forword" style="width: 100px; display:none;" class="k-button" onclick="    PostMessageDetails(3)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="btnNew" value="New" style="width: 80px;display:none;" class="k-button" onclick="    clearMsgFields(); showHideMsgButton('new');" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="btnCancel" value="Discard" style="width: 100px;" class="k-button" onclick="    clearMsgFields(); showHideMsgButton('cancel');" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="btnSendReply"  value="Send" style="width: 100px; display:none;" class="k-button" onclick="    PostMessageDetails(2)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="btnDiscard" value="Discard" style="width: 100px; display:none;" class="k-button" />
        @*<input type="button" id="btnSend" value="Send" style="width: 100px;(@TempData["SendDisplayValue"] != null) ? @TempData["SendDisplayValue"]: display:block;" class="k-button" onclick="PostMessageDetails(1)"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="btnReply"  value="Reply" style="width: 100px; (@TempData["ReplyDisplayValue"] !=null) ? @TempData["ReplyDisplayValue"] : display:none;" class="k-button" onclick="    PostMessageDetails(2)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="btnForword" value="Forword" style="width: 100px; display:none;" class="k-button" onclick="    PostMessageDetails(3)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="btnNew" value="New" style="width: 80px; display:none;" class="k-button" onclick="    PostMessageDetails(2);" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="btnCancel" value="Discard" style="width: 100px; " class="k-button" onclick="@TempData["onCalcelFunction"]"  />*@
    </div>

 }
```

And code on 'tab2' which contains kendo grid. And in ClientDetailTemplate of this grid i wants to load content of 'tab1'

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Validators/_MessagesList.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")"></script>
<style>
    /*<span class="k-icon k-delete"></span>*/
    /*<span class="k-icon k-delete"></span>Delete*/
        span.k-delete {
            background: url("../../../Images/deletes.gif");
        }
        .k-grid .k-button-icontext .k-icon {
            margin: 0;
            vertical-align: middle;
            background-color:transparent;
            border:none;
        }
        .k-grid tbody .k-button {
            min-width: 30px;
            width: 30px;
            border:none;
        }
    .unreadRows
    {
        font-weight:bold;
    }

.k-grid td{
border-color:transparent;
}
    </style>
<div id="divContainer" >
    <div id="replyMsgURL" data-request-url="@Url.Action("SendMessageView", "Account")"></div>
    <div id="loader" data-request-url="@Url.Action("changeMsgStatus", "Account")"></div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("MessageListView", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "_messagesListViewForm" }))
                    {  

<table  class="formStyle" style="width:100%;">
                              <tr>
                                  <td>
                                      <table style="width:100%;">
                                          <tr>
                                              <td>
                                                   InBox<input type="radio" name="msgType" id="rdInBox" value="true" style="width:5%" checked="checked" onclick="fillMsgList()"/>

                                                  Sent<input type="radio" name="msgType" id="rdSent" value="true"  style="width:5%"  onclick="fillMsgList()"/>

                                                  Draft<input type="radio" name="msgType" id="rdDraft" value="true"  style="width:5%" onclick="fillMsgList()" />
                                              </td>
                                          </tr>
                                      </table>
                                  </td>
                              </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>

            @Html.Kendo().Window().Name("wdwMsg").Title("Message").Draggable().Height(200).Width(200).Content(@<div id="divMsg"></div>)
        </td>
    </tr>
                              <tr>
                                  <td>
                                      @{

                                      <div id="divGrid" >
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<PatientPortal.Model.Data.CommunicationMessasge>()    
    .Name("GridMsgList")
    .CellAction(cell =>
      {

          if (cell.DataItem.Status == 2)
        {
            cell.HtmlAttributes["style"] = "color:gray";

        }

      }
    )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {


        columns.Bound(m => m.MessageId).Groupable(false).Hidden();        
        columns.Bound(m => m.MessageFrom).Title("From").HtmlAttributes("grName:GrdRow;");
        columns.Bound(m => m.MessageTo).Title("To");
        columns.Bound(m => m.Subject);
        columns.Bound(m => m.MessageDate).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").Title("Date");
        columns.Command(command => { command.Destroy().Text(""); }).Title("Delete").Width("20px");
       })

    .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
                            .Pageable()
                            .Sortable()
                            .Filterable()
                            .Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBound"))
                            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                .Ajax()
                                .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                                .Read(read => read.Action("GetPatientMessage", "Account").Data("getMsgType")).PageSize(10)
                                .Model(model => model.Id(m => m.MessageId))
                                .Destroy(delete => delete.Action("deleteMassage", "Account").Data("getMsgType"))                               
                            )

                        )
    </div>      

                                      }
                                  </td>
                              </tr>
                          </table>


}
    </div>
  <script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">

     <div id="divOuter" class="dashContentBlock divShadowOuter" >
   <div id="divDetails_#=MessageId#">
       <ul style="list-style:none">
           <li><b>From:</b> #= MessageFrom #</li>
           <li><b>To:</b> #= MessageTo #</li>
           <li><b>Subject:</b> #= Subject #</li>
           <li><b>Message:</b> #= Comments #</li>
           <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
           <li><input  type="button" value="Reply" title="Reply" class="k-button" style="width: 100px;" onclick="EditMesg(#:MessageId#,#:Status#,'#= MessageFrom #')"/></li>
           </ul>
   </div>
    <div id="divViewContainer_#=MessageId#" style="display:none;" >
        <div id="divView_#=MessageId#" style="border:0px none none;" >
            </div>

        </div>
</div>
</script>
```

and this function is used to load the content of 'tab1' to 'tab2'

```
function EditMesg(id, Status, MessageFrom) {
    var replyUrl = $("#replyMsgURL").data('request-url');
    $("#divView_" + id).load(replyUrl, { 'id': id },
                                    function (response, status, xhr) {
                                        //set SendMessagePartial
                                        $('#btnNew').hide();
                                        $('#btnSend').hide();
                                        $('#btnReply').hide();
                                        $('#btnForword').hide();
                                        $('#btnCancel').hide();
                                        $('#btnSendReply').show();
                                        $('#btnDiscard').show();
                                        $("#MessageTo").data("kendoAutoComplete").value(MessageFrom);
                                        //$("#MessageTo").data("kendoAutoComplete").readonly(true);
                                        $("#btnDiscard").click(function () {
                                            $("#divViewContainer_" + id).hide();
                                            $("#divDetails_" + id).show();
                                            var $form = $('#_sendMessageViewForm');
                                            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
                                        });
                                        if (status == "error") {
                                        }

                                    });
    $("#divViewContainer_" + id).show();
    $("#divDetails_" + id).hide();

}
```

Comment: Can you post the output of markup or source code for the view?

Comment: Thank you Stokedout for reply!                                  Sorry Stokedout:(i cant post output.but it seems like style-sheet problem.after reducing the width of controls.error displays half on view content and half outside.do you have any idea?but i cat reduce width of my controls it should be big enough.

Comment: Just use Firebug to check the styles applied to each part of your html. Also validate the html to make sure you have closed all tags. Most likely the razor page wouldn't run anyway but worth a try.

Comment: Hi,i have added piece of code.